# codeigniter form_validation with ajax

Tags: codeigniter-3

When i submit it with no data, it shows like this. but i want it to show on my modal, because i'm using the form_validation library.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WCwxz.png)

This is my Controller:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('category_name','Category name','trim|required');
            if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE){
                echo validation_errors();
            } else{
                $category = array(
                    "category_name" => $this->input->post('category_name')
                ); 
                $this->category_m->insert($category);
                echo "Successfully Added.";
            }
```

This is my ajax file:

```
$(document).on('submit', '#form' ,function(event){
            event.preventDefault();
            var form = $(this).serialize();
            $.ajax({
                url:"<?php echo base_url(); ?>category/operation",
                type:"POST",
                data:form,
                success:function(data){
                    $('#form')[0].reset();
                    $('#mymodal').modal('hide');
                    $('#alert').fadeIn().html('<div class="alert alert-info">'+data+'</div>').fadeOut(5000);
                    table.ajax.reload();
                }
            }) 
        });
```

Comment: Could you please explain better what you want to do?

Comment: @Icssanshes i want the validation error shows inside my modal, when i submit it without a data. but it shows like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This is not related to Codeigniter.** It's JS/jQuery/HTML/...

Assuming that you have something like this in your HTML

```
<div id="mymodal">...</div>
```

Create another `div#alert` inside

```
<div id="alert">...</div>
```

And change the Javascript to something like

```
//You don't neet fadeIn/fadeOut
$('#alert').html('<div class="alert alert-info">'+data+'</div>');
$('#mymodal').modal('show');
```

Comment: yeah i do have this <span class="text-danger"><?php echo form_error('category_name'); ?></span> in my modal,so i can show the error in my modal.